# Directory.GetParent and slashes

Tags: c#, path

Running this snippet

```
var path1 = @"C:\Temp\SomeFolder";
var path2 = @"C:\Temp\SomeFolder\";
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetParent(path1));
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetParent(path2));
```

Output

> C:\Temp
>
> C:\Temp\SomeFolder

Same story with `Path.GetDirectoryName()`, which also can be used to obtain parent folder, but will similarly *fail* in case of `\` at the end.

I do really like `Path.Combine()` for ignoring slashes at the end and do really hate some guys who make some methods returning path with slash (referring to [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) ***angryface***).

Question: how to properly handle possible slash at the end of given path when I need to get one of the parent directories?

---

Here is another snippet

```
var path1 = @"C:\Temp\SomeFolder";
var path2 = @"C:\Temp\SomeFolder\";
var dir1 = @"Test";
var dir2 = @"Test\";
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path1, dir1));
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path1, dir2));
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path2, dir1));
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(path2, dir2));
```

Output

> C:\Temp\SomeFolder\Test
>
> C:\Temp\SomeFolder\Test\
>
> C:\Temp\SomeFolder\Test
>
> C:\Temp\SomeFolder\Test\

`Path.Combine` works *properly* (ignoring ending slash of the first path, or well, adding it when it's missing), while persisting ending slash of second path (for whatever reasons, I do not care, because using resulting path in more `Path.Combines` will works as well).

As I understand `Test` and `Test\` pointing at the same folder in directory structure. And if I want to get *parent* (previous folder), then `Directory.GetParent` should return me previous folder, and **not** `Test` folder again.

Comment: It is not a _fail_. This is how pathes work. After the `\\` you are _one level deeper_

Comment: @DrKoch (or comment upvoters), can you please explain that "one level deeper"? I understand paths from MS-DOS times (`dir` and such). Look e.g at `BaseDirectory`, it returns me path with slash at the end, in my understanding both (with slash and without slash) are targeting same folder, there are no more sub-folders in there, so what is this *level* what goes *deeper*?

Comment: See my answer below for further details

Comment: Please see edit, I could think what without slash  I am targeting folder itself and with slash - content of that folder, but with this theory I should call method `Directory.GetParent` **twice** for each parent - one time to progress to *pointer at previous folder content* and another to get folder itself. Notice what `Directory.GetParent` however will not return path with slash at the end. So "one level deeper" thing is very unclear to me and bugs me a lot now.

Comment: `Path.Combine` is very clever and works around all these different _conventions_ for a "good" folder path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: how to properly handle possible slash at the end of given
>   path when I need get one of the parent directories?

Just trim it from the input string. Use `TrimEnd`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetParent(path1.TrimEnd('\\')));
```

However returning the complete path when the string is terminated by `\` is desired behaviour

[Directory.GetParent Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> However, passing "C:\Directory\SubDirectory\" returns
>   "C:\Directory\SubDirectory", because the ending directory separator is
>   after "SubDirectory".

Comment: This was helpful in demystifying the seemingly illogical behavior I was seeing with `GetParent()`. Especially after coming from `path.resolve()` and `path.join()` in Node.Js, the trailing slash problem never occurred to me

Answer (score 1):

Some Path theory:

A file system contains Containers (Folders, Directories) and Elements (Files).

A "Path" Contains a set of (hierarchical) Containers and probably an "Element" as last element, all separated by slashes.

In theory, if the "Element" is missing, there is a trailing slash to indicate that the last item is a Container:

> /Directory/Subdirectory/

And a Path without trailing slash points to an "Element", not an "Container"

> /Directory/Subdirectory/Element

This is the theoretically clean way to handle things. Because it is often too cumbersome for end-users to deal with clean theory, the software often *tolerates* a missing trailing slash after a final "Container":

> /Directory/Subdirectory

This is just a "hack" to make the life of the end-user easier and basically agiuants the theoretically sound specs for pathes.

---

**Edit**

This convention has its drawbacks and introduces missbehaviour at different places.

Look at the `Directory.GetParent()` method. It accepts a string and works with string manipulations only. So this method can not decide if the last item is a "Container" or an "Element" if the trailing slash is missing. It assumes to see an "Element" as last element and returns the next "Container". If the last item happens to be a "Container" (and we mean "all content in this container") this is indeed the wrong answer.

Comment: Big thanks for effort put into explaining this. To summarize, you are saying what in .Net ending slash in paths means what path is **not complete** somehow? E.g. `Directory.GetParent(@"c:\temp\123.txt")` returns `c:\temp`. So ending slash is a part of `Regex` or whatever to remove possible *file* names at the end of path??

Comment: Yes. `C:\temp\\ ` is a theoretically correct path for the Container `temp`

Comment: `Directory.GetParent` conflicts with your theory. The parent container should *never* be an element, so why would the parent of `C:\Directory\ ` be `C:\Directory`? The lack of an ending slash implies that `C:\Directory` is an element. In order to adhere to the theory the result of `GetParent` should always end with a slash, implying that the intuitive return value and the theoretically sound return value are both `C:\ `.